# Equilibrium states for the Curie-Weiss-Potts model and large deviations

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am doing a project in Large deviation theory applied to statistical mechanics and I was reading this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0410744.

For the general setting we start with a finite state space $\Gamma=\{ x_1,\dots,x_q \}$ and we consider the triple $(\Omega_n,\mathscr{F},P_n)$ where $\Omega_n=\Gamma^n$, $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $P_n$ is the product measure. We also have a bounded random variable

$$H_n: \Omega_n \to \mathbb{R} $$

called the Hamiltonian that measures the interaction between particles among other physical considerations. The microcanonical ensemble in then defined to be the triple $(\Omega_n,\mathscr{F},P^{u,r}_n)$ where $P^{u,r}_n$ denotes the conditional measure that assigns $0$ probability to $\omega \in \Omega_n$ such that $H_n/n(\omega) \notin [u-r,u+r]$.

If we can find that the measures $h_n=H_n/n$ satisfy a large deviation property when $ n \to \infty, r \to 0$ it is clear to me that the equilibrium macrostates should be those that minimize the entropy function. However at this moment it is not clear to me why if we start with this Curie-Weiss-Potts model we can say that the equilibrium macrostates of the system are exactly the measures that minimize the entropy function of the empirical vectors.

Could someone clarify this?